# Update Table1 from Table3 joined by Table2, but Table 2 may refer to multiple table3 entries

Tags: mysql, join

If I wanted to update a `table1` field with a value from `table3`, joining with `table2`, I would do:

```
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.code = t3.code
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
ON t2.id = t3.id_from_t2;
```

But in this particular case, there might be many `table3` entries where `t2.id = t3.id_from_t2`, and I want to get `t3.code` with lower value (is a number) among those where `t3.active` is 1.

How to achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to a modified select from t3 like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN (select tt3.id_from_t2 , min(tt3.code) as code
            from table3 AS tt3
            where tt3.active = 1
            group by tt3.id_from_t2) t3
ON t2.id = t3.id_from_t2
SET t1.code = t3.code;
```

That way t3 sub query contains only id_from_t2 and the min code where active = 1, so you will have only one value.